# How to fix Altair error when code appears to be right

Tags: pandas, altair

```
    Name    Gender  Value   Year    Measure
0   A       boy     3451    2021    Rank
1   A-Jay   boy     3451    2021    Rank
2   A.J.    boy     0       2021    Rank
3   Aaban   boy     3990    2021    Rank
4   Aabid   boy     0       2021    Rank
```

My code:`enter code here`

```
# Create the Altair chart
selector_metric = alt.selection_single(name='Select', fields=['Measure'], init={'Measure': 'Rank'}, bind={'Measure': alt.binding_select(options=['Rank', 'Count'])})
selector_gender = alt.selection_multi(name='Gender', fields=['Gender'], bind='legend')


chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_line(point=True).encode(
    x='Year:O',
    y='Value:Q',
    color='Gender:N',
    tooltip=['Name', 'Gender', 'Measure', 'Value'],
    opacity=alt.condition(selector_gender, alt.value(1), alt.value(0.2))
).add_selection(
    selector_metric,
    selector_gender
).transform_filter(
    selector_metric
).properties(
    title='Time Series Plot of Baby Names Popularity'
)

chart
```

Error:

```
TypeError: altair.vegalite.v5.schema.core.SelectionParameter() got multiple values for keyword argument 'value'
```

Answer (score 1):

`alt.selection_single` is deprecated in Altair v5. Use `alt.selection_point` instead:

```py
selector_metric = alt.selection_point(
    name='Select', 
    fields=['Measure'], 
    bind={'Measure': alt.binding_select(options=['Rank', 'Count'])},
    value='Rank',
)

selector_gender = alt.selection_point(
    name='Gender', 
    fields=['Gender'], 
    bind='legend',
)

chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_line(point=True).encode(
    x='Year:O',
    y='Value:Q',
    color='Gender:N',
    tooltip=['Name', 'Gender', 'Measure', 'Value'],
    opacity=alt.condition(selector_gender, alt.value(1), alt.value(0.2))
).add_params(
    selector_metric,
    selector_gender
).transform_filter(
    selector_metric
).properties(
    title='Time Series Plot of Baby Names Popularity'
)

chart
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).